# Is there a way to make a field only editable by a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In Sql Server 2008 is there a way to set a field that it can only be changed using a Trigger?

Example:

When you create a record it is set to NULL and then updated by a trigger to e.g 1.
It should not be able to be set to anything other than NULL by the user.
And then when it is updated the trigger will set the value to 2.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What is the *real* problem?

Comment: I want a field that can not be updated by the user through an update or insert. I want the value of the field to be governed by database logic. (This is for setting the version of a record) - I want the only the database logic to govern the value field

Comment: If you want this for row versioning, why not use the built in `rowversion` type? It won't guarantee sequential values, but it ought to do a good enough job. It's already built and doesn't allow its value to be set by users. And it doesn't depend on triggers not being disabled.

Comment: The right answer to my question was "I need row versions." It takes a fair bit of experience to recognize and dig yourself out from under an XY problem. (That's an observation, not a criticism.)

Comment: This is true. However I want to do this for other things such as the Time that the record was created(there is probably a type for this) and also another Text Field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table tmp (a int primary key, b int)
GO

create trigger tr_insupd_tmp on tmp
instead of insert, update
as
    if not exists(select * from deleted)
        -- Process Insert
        insert into tmp
            select a, 1
            from inserted
    else
        -- Process Update
        update tmp
            set b = 2
        from tmp t
        inner join inserted i on t.a = i.a
GO
```

Comment: You've taken this fairly literally - the implication is that further updates will increment the value, not just set it = 2 each time.

Comment: This is an example of how to solve the problem of controlling the setting of a field through a trigger. I took the logic in the question as just an example of what was required. In any case, changing it to do what you say is trivial.

Comment: I think this has potential !

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using using computed columns. If you want data in this column to be only governed by database logic then computed columns are probably way to go.